# prepend list in reverse according comment post jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm building a comment system where anytime I create a new comment it positions right on top of the comment form..this way:

```js
$('button').on("click", function(){

var text = "text";
$(".commentbox").prepend("<li>comment n</li>");


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li>this is a comment</li>
<li>this is a comment</li>
<li>this is a comment</li>
<li class="commentbox">
<button>create comment</button>
</li>


</ul>
```

So the order would be.....1,2,3,4,5 descending....(5 is the last comment posted)

How can it make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to that the new comments on clicking the button must be shown at top the I Hope the below correction solves your issue.

```js
$('button').on("click", function(){

var text = "text";
$(".commentbox").prepend("<li>comment n</li>");


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="commentbox">
<li>this is a comment</li>
<li>this is a comment</li>
<li>this is a comment</li>
<li>
<button>create comment</button>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: no....thank you. .the last comment always have to stay sticked to the comment form at the bottom.